# How to add username with FirebaseAuth in android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Firebase register code is given below. When I add username as a parameter, the method does not let me do it.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    }else{
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Bir hata oldu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: And what do you mean with "does not let me to do it"? It shows any error?

Comment: I want save username or name with email and password  when user registered. Than display it

Comment: method does not let more parameter than email and password parameters

Comment: Are you trying to create new user? What parameters do you want to add ?

Comment: @ErginErsoy I want use username, email and password.  But firebaseauth only let email and password.

Comment: i explained below how you can add username to user

Answer (score 3):

you need to update user after creating it.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            addUserNameToUser(task.getResult().getUser());
        }
    }
)};
private void addUserNameToUser(User user){
    String username = "username";
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String userId = user.getUid();

    User user = new User(username, email);

    firebaseDB.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

the variable `firebaseDB` should be created before. You can create in where you create `firebaseAuth` like so ;

```
firebaseDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

**Update 1**
using `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("erginersoyy@gmail.com", "12345").addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    addUserNameToUser(task.getResult().getUser());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addUserNameToUser(FirebaseUser user) {
        String username = "username";

        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(username)
                .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
                .build();

        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

you can also check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

Comment: Is this what you were trying to do

Comment: having a problem in photo in answer up

Comment: I get error at  addUserNameToUser(task.getResult().getUser());with error User can not applied to Firebase

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq. :(